# striped background for the border of a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a code with me which has a solid color for a div element's border.
My question is, is it possible to give this border a striped effect?

Sample this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #panel {
        padding: 50px text-align: center;
        background-color: #e5eecc;
        border: solid 10px #c3c3c3;
    }
</style>

<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

The border's background here is solid grey, i.e, #e5eecc. In place of that i want a stripe(zebra kind of).
Preferably using jquery.

Comment: `border-style` can do dotted or dashed borders. If you wanna set with `jQuery` use `.css()`

Answer (score 2):

Use border images:

http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

like so:

```
border-image:url(images/stripe.png) 15 20 30 30 repeat;
border-width: 15px 20px 30px 30px;
```

Then [generate a stripe image](http://www.stripegenerator.com/) pattern that repeats itself.

*note - IE of version less than 11 does not support this.* (depends if you care or not)

Another way is to put a striped backgroud the some element which wraps your div, give that element padding, and then give you div a background color, say #FFF. creates the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

A striped effect is possible with `dashed`:

```
border: dashed 10px #c3c3c3;
```

or using jQuery:

```
$("#panel").css("border","dashed 10px #c3c3c3")
```

Note that you can change `c3c3c3` to `black` if you want it to be exactly zebra-like.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/t9Q7c/)